# Child Category Conditional Question

Tags: categories

I am trying to display images if a child category is selected however when a child category is not selected I want to display a message saying its not available. The below code works to display the images however I cannot seem to correctly add the code that displays message if no child category is selected.

```
foreach((get_the_category()) as $childcat) {
if (cat_is_ancestor_of(210, $childcat)) {

  echo '<img src="/wp-content/themes/Bootstrap/images/flags/';
  echo $childcat->slug;
  echo '.png" alt="';
  echo $childcat->cat_name;
  echo '" title="';
  echo $childcat->cat_name;
  echo '" style="width:28px;height:20px;border-radius:20px;"> ';

}}
```

Below is a working conditional however it does not display all the child categories like the code above.

```
if (is_category_or_sub(210)) {

  echo '<img src="/wp-content/themes/Bootstrap/images/flags/';
  echo $childcat->slug;
  echo '.png" alt="';
  echo $childcat->cat_name;
  echo '" title="';
  echo $childcat->cat_name;
  echo '" style="width:28px;height:20px;border-radius:20px;"> ';

} else {
  echo 'Sorry This Movie Is Not Available';
}
```

Here is it in action: http://netflix.rhgfx.com/life-itself/

its the availability column on the left.

Comment: What is `is_category_or_sub()`?

Comment: I found that code using Google.  I am not sure what the exact PHP call is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what `is_category_or_sub()` and that function is the critical piece of code. Without it, the question of why your code doesn't work isn't answerable but [there is code in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category#Testing_if_a_post_is_in_a_descendant_category) that seems to do what you need:

```
/**
 * Tests if any of a post's assigned categories are descendants of target categories
 *
 * @param int|array $cats The target categories. Integer ID or array of integer IDs
 * @param int|object $_post The post. Omit to test the current post in the Loop or main query
 * @return bool True if at least 1 of the post's categories is a descendant of any of the target categories
 * @see get_term_by() You can get a category by name or slug, then pass ID to this function
 * @uses get_term_children() Passes $cats
 * @uses in_category() Passes $_post (can be empty)
 * @version 2.7
 * @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category#Testing_if_a_post_is_in_a_descendant_category
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'post_is_in_descendant_category' ) ) {
    function post_is_in_descendant_category( $cats, $_post = null ) {
        foreach ( (array) $cats as $cat ) {
            // get_term_children() accepts integer ID only
            $descendants = get_term_children( (int) $cat, 'category' );
            if ( $descendants && in_category( $descendants, $_post ) )
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And ...

```
if ( in_category( 210 ) || post_is_in_descendant_category( 210 ) ) {
    // In the category
} else {
    // not in the category
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much but unfortunately that does not work.  In a nutshell, I would like the flags (which are child categories of 'Availability') to display if any of them are checked in the back-end and if none are checked it would say "Not Available".  I am hope I am being clear, thank you for your time.  The first code displays them and the 2nd code does the "Not Available" function, so in essence I am looking for a combination of both codes.

Comment: I made a couple of edits to make the answer more clear, but I don't see why this wouldn't work.

Comment: I have tried it, it does not list out the child categories so I am able to make the flag images work.  It simply allows me to put data there but I need to be able to list out the child categories to replace the text with flag images.  Note - how on this post there is a list of flags: http://netflix.rhgfx.com/life-itself/ those are each child categories, that I used the echo output to make images.

Comment: Nevermind, this is correct.  It just took some tweaking.  Thank you very much for your time and effort.